# Problems displaying Dialog in Android

Tags: java, android

Every time I try to run this simple app, I get this error:

Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

But if I change this line:

```
vdlgDialogToShow = new Dialog(this);
```

and add it to `onCreate` instead, it works.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button vbtnShowDialog;
private Dialog vdlgDialogToShow;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    vbtnShowDialog = findViewById(R.id.btnShowDialog);

    vbtnShowDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            displayValidateEmailPopup();

        }
    });

}

public void displayValidateEmailPopup(){

    // Criando variável necessária para mostrar a Dialog
    vdlgDialogToShow = new Dialog(getApplicationContext());

    vdlgDialogToShow.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

    // Construindo Dialog
    vdlgDialogToShow.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
    ImageView ivCloseWarningPopup = vdlgDialogToShow.findViewById(R.id.ivWarningDialogCloseImage);
    TextView vtvDialogTitleText = vdlgDialogToShow.findViewById(R.id.tvWarningDialogTitle);
    TextView vtvDialogBodyText = vdlgDialogToShow.findViewById(R.id.tvWarningDialogBodyText);
    ImageView vivDialogImage = vdlgDialogToShow.findViewById(R.id.ivWarningDialogImage);
    Button vbtnEnviarEmailConfirmacao = vdlgDialogToShow.findViewById(R.id.btnWarningDialogButton);

    // Populando os campos da Dialog
    vtvDialogTitleText.setText(R.string.warning_dialog_email_nao_confirmado_title);
    vtvDialogBodyText.setText(R.string.warning_dialog_email_nao_confirmado_body);
    vivDialogImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_mail_white_dialog_warning);
    vbtnEnviarEmailConfirmacao.setText(R.string.enviar_email_button_text);

    // Verificando se a imagem que representa o fechamento da Dialog foi clicada
    ivCloseWarningPopup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            vdlgDialogToShow.dismiss();
        }
    });

    // Verificando se o Botão de enviar email de confirmação foi clicado
    vbtnEnviarEmailConfirmacao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Verificando se o dispositivo está conectado à rede
        }
    });

    vdlgDialogToShow.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

    // Exibindo Dialog
    vdlgDialogToShow.show();

}
}
```

I just would like to know why. This is probably a rookie question. But any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, it works just by changing `getApplicationContext()` to `this`.
The reason for that `getApplicationContext()` is used to refer to the entire application which is used for application level. A dialog is part of an activity and hence, you cannot use application level context to initialize dialog.

*Happy coding*

Comment: Thanks, I hope the author will understand

Answer (score 0):

It happened because you are showing your popup too early before activity is created and the parameter `this` is refereed to the context of the activity which is null before the creation of activity  !

To avoid `BadTokenException`, you need to defer showing the popup until  `onCreate()`methods is called which means activity window is displayed .

and that's why it works fine when you put the code in `onCreate`